# Making each item in a object in a array update once a object is deleted

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

So I made a discord bot recently and I made a warning system,so basicly,I have my object(this is in mongodb btw):

```
{
_id: '0123',
warns: [
 {
  pos: 1,
  reason: 'apples r blue'
 },
 {
  pos: 2,
  reason: 'apples r red'
 }
]}
```

so the array is longer but i wanna keep it short,so basicly everytime a object in the array is deleted,i want each `pos` to be updated,for example,i delete

```
 {
  pos: 1,
  reason: 'apples r blue'
 }
```

and i want the second object

```
 {
  pos: 2,
  reason: 'apples r red'
 }
```

pos's to be updated to 1,now this seems easy but i wanna do this for ALL objects,but lets say i have the array like this now:

```
warns: [
 {
  pos: 1,
  reason: 'apples r blue'
 },
 {
  pos: 2,
  reason: 'apples r red'
 },
 {
  pos: 3,
  reason: 'apples r red'
 },
 {
  pos: 4,
  reason: 'apples r red'
 },
 {
  pos: 5,
  reason: 'apples r red'
 }
]}
```

and lets say i suddenly removed the object with a pos of `3`,then i want 4 and 5 to be updated as well (4 becomes 3 and 5 becomes 4 and so on),i know how to update the objects but cant think of a method as its 5am right now and im tired,so i hope someone will suggest a method

Comment: What do you need that for? You could just use the index in your array (maybe with some offset) and it would yield the same result...

Comment: ah i forgot to mention i dunno how to update the object's value inside the object that is inside the array

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you only want to know how to update values in an array, here it is:

```
array.map((value) => {
  value.pos--;
  return value;
};
```